# Passing arguments to intent android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the first intent, it starts the second intent. In the second intent, I get the values, and pass the value to the first content and close the second content. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: use `putExtra` or a `Bundle` object

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass parameters to the intent when you create it. If you need to pass objects you need to implement Parcelable interface on the object you pass:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
MyData j = new MyData();
i.putExtra("MyParameter", "Something");
i.putExtra("MyData", j); //only works if MyData implements Parcelable
startActivity(i);
```

In the second activity you can read your data:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
if(extras.containsKey("MyParameter")) {
    String something = i.getStringExtra("MyParameter");
}
if(extras.containsKey("MyData")) {
    MyData otherthing = i.getParcelableExtra("MyData");
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try this

**Passing the parameter to using intent i am passing the message like this**

```
     Intent intent= new Intent(mContext,SuccessActivity.class);

     intent.putExtra("message",mContext.getString(R.string.success_sign_msg));
```

**Get value using intent**

```
     Intent intent=getIntent();
    success_msg_txt.setText(intent.getStringExtra("message"));
```

try this it helps you