# How to pass a variable through an intent in Android Studio, in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

I want to pass a variable through a button from one class to another using intents.

This is the code I have so far:

Class A:

```
     val i = Intent (this, ClassB::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("IS_BLUE", 1)
        startActivity(i)
```

to class B:

```
val isBlue: Long = intent . getLongExtra("IS_BLUE", 0)
```

I am trying to write an if statement to check if it equals 1 or 0. Since the default value is 0 it keeps taking that as the variable instead of what I put it to be in the previous class and going for the else statement.

```
 if (isBlue.equals(1)) { ... } else { ... }
```

I might have gotten my types wrong but when I tried with

```
intent.getIntExtra("IS_BLUE", 0)
```

I was getting the same issues and some errors in my if statement as well. I am getting no errors and I can run my app fine, I just can't get the variable to pass. Please help.

Comment: Let the compiler do the heavy work. For instance,`isBlue: Long`, that can be derived by the compiler. Use `isBlue == 1` or better, use `intent.putExtra("IS_BLUE", true)` and use `if (isBlue)`

Comment: I get a type mismatch because it's now asking for a Boolean but I specified long. Also when I change it to Boolean, it keeps returning the fefault value still.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: I am doing a project for UNI so I don't want to get any misconduct going on. This is all the relevant code I can post I think.

Comment: Your question says that you're checking for the value in "class B", but your `Intent` seems to be directing you to `ClassA`... is this a typo?

Comment: Where is your `val isBlue = intent.get...` code located? Inside `onCreate()`?

Comment: It is inside onMapReady() which is inside my main class along with onCreate()

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing between two convertible types which gives wrong output.

Try using

```
val isBlue = intent.getIntExtra("IS_BLUE", 0)

if (isBlue == 1) { ... } else { ... }
```

Instead of

```
if (isBlue.equals(1)) { ... } else { ... }
```

Comment: I had that previously and had to change the getLongExtra to getIntExtra because the if statement wouldn't compile otherwise, but same issue.

Comment: If you want to use Long, then you have to put `L` beside 1 like `1L`

Comment: It keeps returning the default value still.

Comment: Probably you call this `val isBlue: Long = intent . getLongExtra("IS_BLUE", 0)` outside `onCreate`. Am I right?

Comment: Actually I have a map activity that opens up when a button is clicked. I want the isBlue to determine the color of markers that pop up on the map. I was creating it inside a method called onMapReady and it didn't crash my code. But when I tried to create it outside of the method it would load the app but crash as soon as I clicked the button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using intent.getIntExtra()
try:

```
intent.extras?.getInt("IS_BLUE",0)
```

or intent.extras?.getLong("IS_BLUE") or  intent.extras?.get("IS_BLUE") depending on the dataType you used to pass the data.

Comment: It just uses null as the value now. If I try and put the getLongExtra line anywhere else but the actual method, my app crashes. But if it's in the method then it points to null.

Comment: you mean the value of the expression : intent.extras?.getInt("IS_BLUE",0) is null? then you are not passing the arguments correctly. Check the examples here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181747/passing-arguments-to-intent-android

Comment: also please check this line of code: val i = Intent (this, ClassA::class.java)
you say your secondActivity is ClassB and you are putting the data in Class A. right?
Then, the correct intent should be sth like,
val i = Intent (this, ClassB::class.java)