# Android - on click notification save string in Shared Preferences

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm still not very good in Android dev, and I'm trying to figure out how can I do trigger some action (in my case I want to save a variable in shared preferences) after I click a Notification in Android.

I currently have this code:

```
private void startForegroundService() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Start " + NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME + " foreground service");
        setNotificationLanguage();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(getResourceIdForResourceName(this, "ic_stat_show_chart"))
                .setSound(null)
                .setContentTitle(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME)
                .setContentText(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESC)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
}
```

When I click the notification I launch my MainActivity class, which is something that I also want. But I would also like to save a string in Shared Preferences in the notification is clicked. I already searched and found nothing. If someone could help I would appreciate it. Thank you :)

Comment: check for intent in your main activity

Comment: Try to work it in the way I coded. You can accept my answer if it's working @Johny . Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Keshav explained, You can get the data from the intent and store it in the sharedpreferences, Here is SharedPreferenceHelper class.

```
public class SharedPreferenceHelper {

 private static final String STRING_NAME = "your_string_name";

 public SharedPreferenceHelper(Context context) {
    mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
  }

 public void setString(String your_string){
    mPreferences.edit().putString(STRING_NAME,your_string).apply();
}

public String getString(){
    return mPreferences.getString(STRING_NAME,null);
}

}
```

In the MainActivity,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

 Bundle mBundle;
 SharedPreferenceHelper mSharedPreferenceHelper;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSharedPreferenceHelper = new SharedPreferenceHelper(this);
    mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(mBundle != null){
     mSharedPreferenceHelper.setString(mBundle.getString("your_string_data"));
     }

}
```

If activity is already created then,

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
  if(mBundle != null){
     mSharedPreferenceHelper.setString(mBundle.getString("your_string_data"));
     }
}

enter code here
```

Let me Know if you have any issues.

Comment: What if the MainActivity is already created? Should I do it also in onResume(), for example?

Comment: Yeah but check if the bundle is null before you put the preference value @JohnyBoy

Comment: Ok update your answer if you can, so I accept it. I think this is important. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Sure . Thank you @JohnyBoy

Answer (score 1):

Try doing below in your Main Activty:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtras()){
   //Saved notification has been clicked to shared preferences
}
```

Hope this might help

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments to intent, and in MainActivity check is intent have arguments
[Passing arguments to intent android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181747/passing-arguments-to-intent-android)

Answer (score 1):

Add String value which you want to save your sharedpref as extra in your `notificationIntent`, something like below.

```
notificationIntent.putExtra("Key","Value");
```

You will be able to extract it in your `onCreate` of your Activity.

```
 String value = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Key");
```

**Note:** If you just want to know if the activity is opened by notification, just pass any constant value in intent and check if you get that in the   `onCreate` using the above approach, that way you are sure that the activity is launched by notification. Just make sure in that condition not to use the same key/value combination as extras for the same activity intent from launching it from anywhere else other than notification pendingIntent flow.

Answer (score 1):

Override method onNewIntent in your MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("KEY", "str value"); //change this according to your need
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: You are completely right. Its better to use onNewIntent, since the onCreate method only triggers if the MainActivity is not already running. Thank you very much!!